# Inconsistent padding on buttons between desktop and mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have built out an example button for this and attached a jsfiddle with the code to demonstrate. The font properties of this particular font force me to use different values for padding along the top and bottom of the text in order to get an evenly spaced button vertically. This works fine on my desktop view and I've simulated it on several device simulation websites as well as Visual Studio Codes device simulator and see no issues.

However, when viewed on an *actual* mobile device, the text is not centered vertically and I can't figure out why. I've tried Chrome, Firefox, and Safari and they all produce the same result using this fiddle and code.

Here's the desktop view of the button:

[image]

Here's the mobile view of the button from my iPhone:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/c4yesf97/15/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');

.myBtn {
  background-color: #cc1818;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0rem auto 0.3125rem auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 black;
  transition: ease-out 0.3s;
}

.myBtnTxt {
  font-family: 'Oswald', Univers, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.6875rem 0rem 0.375rem 0rem;
  margin: 0rem auto 0rem auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="myBtn" style="text-decoration: none;" href="">
  <div class="myBtnTxt">Find Out More</div>
</a>

<a class="myBtn" style="text-decoration: none;" href="">
  <div class="myBtnTxt">Find Out More</div>
</a>
```

I can't seem to figure out what might be causing the phone to interpret the padding differently than what the site and device simulators are seeing. Is there something obvious I'm not catching here? The mobile view is from the actual site it's live on so if you don't have the Oswald font you may not see it the same which is why I provided the screenshots. It still happens with the fallback fonts though. Just wanted to make that clear in case anybody opens the fiddle on their phone and wonders why the fonts are different.

Comment: Does your mobile device have the same fonts installed?

Comment: On desktop, do the words line up nicely if you change the text to "qbdp"?

Comment: Yeah, if you're measuring from the baseline to the cap height it's still equal distance https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/c4yesf97/18/  

I don't have the font installed on my phone but I don't need to. The web provider I'm working with has it hosted on their platform and I rename the "Oswald" font family to their designated identifier "<web provider> Heading Font" and it replaces it with Oswald for me. That's why I took a screenshot from the actual site for the mobile example and not the jsfiddle because that would have looked confusing. It's still not centered with the fallback font though.

Comment: I don't have the font installed on my PC so it fallbacks to Arial and not centered since padding was hard coded for that font. Is that the problem? try removing padding and set `line-height: 2`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't correct it, it just made the padding uneven still on mobile and on desktop. I tried setting vertical align to see if maybe the browser was doing it for me but the text didn't change. I don't know if there's a way to inspect code on a mobile device so that I could see where the browser might be doing something to modify the button text and cause this to occur.

Comment: I tried changing the `padding` values to the `margin` property instead just to see if it made a difference and sadly it did not. I figured maybe if the padding value might be hardcoded it might be interpreted differently on mobile browsers than the margin but I suppose not. Will keep trying though!

Comment: I have embedded the font through Google fonts CDN (otherwise anyone trying to answer the question would only see Arial or whatever fallback font they're using). Interestingly, it now looks bad on desktop but if I remove the padding and use a line height (to simulate top/bottom padding) it looks perfect.

Comment: Thank you for that! I went ahead and did what you suggested and was able to get the spacing correct on the desktop but it's still off on mobile. I'm searching around and I can't seem to find anyone else who has had this happen so I'm just playing with the properties until something clicks. I wonder if it could be a device-specific issue because I know I can scale text on my phone but it doesn't seem to change the way the padding, line height, or margins are interpreted. https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/c4yesf97/58/

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are weird. But there are cool tools like that:
https://seek-oss.github.io/capsize/

With it, you can just remove the spaces around. There are also similar tools.